# How to restore menu bar in Windows 8 Explorer?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

Is there any way to have the old traditional menu bar in Windows 8 Explorer (like in Windows 7)? I'm not comfortable with Explorer's ribbon bar at all, especially its shortcuts.

My favorite way for creating a text file was to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>. I also used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> to bring up the Folder Options dialog, but I can't use them anymore.

I have tried ClassicShell but it has no menu bar. Any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a program called [OldNewExplorer](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-make-your-81-explorer-work-like-win78-one/). It makes Windows 8's explorer like Windows 7's. Now I feel much better.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xplorer<sup>2</sup>](http://www.zabkat.com) or [Directory Opus](http://www.gpsoft.com.au), both of them replace the Ribbon. Also if you just want to disable the ribbon, just double-click on it.

Comment: I don't care about disabling or enabling the ribbon. The ribbon obviously is not designed for keyboard access. I want to use keyboard to do some tasks. This is hard with the ribbon. For now I just go with alternatives like [XYPlorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/) or [Explore++](http://explorerplusplus.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the Ribbon with the expander Arrow button in the top right corner of the Explorer just next to the Help - ? button. Then you might have to relearn a few keyboard shortcuts...

Folder options is available at ALT-V-Y-O. It is not back to the old menu but you win back your screen real estate. BTW many of the Folder Options are available on the View ribbon directly so you might just want to minimize the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

In the control panel go to Folder Options and click the view tab. Check the second item in the list "Always show menus"

Enjoy.

Comment: This doesn't work for the file explorer. but for some reason if you go into control panel it shows the menu still. so it is there.